# Breaking a CTE SQL Query on a particular condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, recursion, common-table-expression

I have following SQL Server CTE Query :

```
  ;with x
 as (
    select childref, 0 as lvl
    from [dbo].[TOMatriX]
    where parentref = @parentref

    union all

    select m.childref, x.lvl+1
    from [dbo].[TOMatriX] m
    inner join x on m.parentref = x.childref
)
select
    lvl [Level],
count(*) [Count], 
    stuff((select ', ' + CAST(ChildRef AS CHAR(9))
           from x t2 where t1.lvl = t2.lvl 
           for xml path('')),
          1,2,'') [Members]
from x t1
group by lvl
```

I need to get details of level upto 12 only, So I have modified above query as :

```
;with x
 as (
    select childref, 0 as lvl
    from [dbo].[TOMatriX]
    where parentref = @parentref

    union all

    select m.childref, x.lvl+1
    from [dbo].[TOMatriX] m
    inner join x on m.parentref = x.childref
)
select top 12
    lvl [Level],
count(*) [Count], 
    stuff((select ', ' + CAST(ChildRef AS CHAR(9))
           from x t2 where t1.lvl = t2.lvl 
           for xml path('')),
          1,2,'') [Members]
from x t1
group by lvl
```

But How can I use OPTION (maxrecursion) to break this recursion on 12th Level, I'm not able to use maxrecursion option in my query, I did try using it as below :

```
;with x
 as (
    select childref, 0 as lvl
    from [dbo].[TOMatriX]
    where parentref = 100000001

    union all

    select m.childref, x.lvl+1
    from [dbo].[TOMatriX] m
    inner join x on m.parentref = x.childref
)
select 
    lvl [Level],
count(*) [Count], 
    stuff((select ', ' + CAST(ChildRef AS CHAR(9))
           from x t2 where t1.lvl = t2.lvl 
           for xml path('')),
          1,2,'') [Members]
from x t1
group by lvl
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 12);
```

But I get following error :

*The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 12 has been exhausted before statement completion.*

So, How can use OPTION (maxrecursion) to stop recursion on 12th Level as done use TOP in 2nd Query.

Note : Table Structre for

```
    TABLE [dbo].[TOMatriX](

        [ParentRef] [int] NOT NULL,
        [ChildRef] [int] NOT NULL,
-- Some Other Columns as well ...

)
```

If possible, Please advice any performance improvements as well.

Comment: You don't want to use `MAXRECURSION`.  It generates an error instead of stopping the recursion.  Instead, add a counter to the recursive CTE and use that to stop the recursion.

Comment: So how can I put LIMITING CONDITION on the recursive query??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of how you put in a limiting condition:

```
with x as (
      select childref, 0 as lvl
      from [dbo].[TOMatriX]
      where parentref = 100000001
      union all
      select m.childref, x.lvl+1
      from [dbo].[TOMatriX] m inner join
           x
           on m.parentref = x.childref
      where x.lvl <= 12
     )
```

Comment: Does "select top 12" also work in the same manner as "where x.lvl <= 12 ?"

Comment: @Pratik . . . Not really.  You shouldn't use `top` without an `order by`.  Your version returns an arbitrary 12 rows from the result set.